# Windows registry - key for default Browser

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, registry

I have a Win 7 64 bit machine. When I set FF or Chrome as the default browser it updates

***HKCR.htm, HKCR.html and HKCR\http***

keys (and may be a few more) to point to the appropriate browser. However when I set IE to be the default browser none of these keys are updated.

I have a program that intends to open html files using the default browser. However this fails when IE is the default browser because the program checks for first two keys mentioned above.

Can someone tell me which keys to look for in order to determine the default browser?

Comment: Check this out http://superuser.com/questions/287313/which-registry-keys-need-to-be-edited-to-change-the-default-browser

Comment: Thanks for replying Roman but I have gone through most of the links mentioned in the post that you mention but it doesn't answer my question. All these posts mention what should be done in order to make a browser the default browser. But my problem is the opposite - IE does not make these settings and even then Win 7 detects it to be the default browser - how does it do so?

Answer (score 1):

You should read

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet
```

If user didn't change default browser away from IE, this registry key under  HKEY_CURRENT_USER won't exist. So, check HKEY_CURRENT_USER first. If not such key/value, check HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE as fallback.

reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd203067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396